# How to group a Class for calculation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got script done where I need to calculate a subtotal per client.
But somehow it does not want to group by clientid (KLNR)

My output is like

```
klnr is: 11111
categorie is: A
Subtotal: 4326 HTML: 4326
klnr is: 11111
categorie is: A
Subtotal: 748 HTML: 748
klnr is: 11111
categorie is: D
klnr is: 22222
categorie is: C
Subtotal: 616 HTML: 616
```

and not having a subtotal from klnr 111111

Code below

```
$(".KLNR").each(function () { 
  var klnr = $(this).val();
  console.log('klnr is: ', klnr);
  if ($.isNumeric($(this).val()  )) {
    var subtotal  = 0;
    var categorie = $(this).parent().children(".CATHINT").val();
    console.log('categorie is: ', categorie);
    if (categorie.contains ("A")||categorie.contains ("C")  ){
      subtotal = subtotal + parseInt($(this).parent().children(".TOTHINT").val()) ;
      console.log("Subtotal: " + subtotal + " HTML: " + 
      $(this).parent().children(".TOTHINT").val()) ;
    }
  }
});
```

Adding HTML code as requested

```
<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE" />
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE" />
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1" />
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="GetCSS" media="screen"></link>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="_file/default.js">xslthelper</script>
    <title>Wachtrij</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_file/jquery.js">xslthelper</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_file/JqueryExt.js">xslthelper</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_file/cookie.js">xslthelper</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
```

Thanks for assisting,

Or should I create it on a different way?

Comment: Please provide jsFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have made an adjustment in my script and created an Array
Now I have the output I want,

```
Sleutel: 11111
getuser...TILMANR (line 51)
Waarde: 5074
getuser...TILMANR (line 52)
Sleutel: 22222
getuser...TILMANR (line 51)
Waarde: 616
```

I added 2 lines of script

```
1 Creation of Array
2 KlnrTotalen[klnr] += subtotal + parseInt($(this).parent().children(".TOTHINT").val()) ;
```

Thanks @Yunus for helping

Answer (score 0):

Change few things and check

```
var categorie = $(this).parent().children(".CATHINT").val();
```

will become

```
var categorie = $(this).closest(".CATHINT").val();
```

and also remove this line

```
subtotal = subtotal + parseInt($(this).parent().children(".TOTHINT").val()) ;
```

and add

```
subtotal = subtotal + parseInt($(this).closest(".TOTHINT").val()) ;
```

Comment: When I change it to closest, I get the issue that it doesn't want to continue, TypeError: categorie is undefined
This message I get on the next step (if)

Comment: Closest is up, children or find is down. If you replace parent() with closest, you need to change children to find

Comment: added the html info from the xsl above

Comment: I'm still confused if this setup will work, as in the end it needs to calculate
klnr is: 11111
Subtotal: 4326 HTML: 4326
klnr is: 11111
Subtotal: 748 HTML: 748
4326 + 748 = subtotal klnr 111111 = 5074